# Find non-ascii characters in string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

`?testMSG=ÁáÉéÍíÑñÓóÚúÜü«»¿¡€`

`<cfset ascii = NOT REFind('[\u0080-\uFFFF]', arguments.textMSG)>`

Variable ascii returns 1, which shouldn't be. REFind('[\u0080-\uFFFF]', arguments.textMSG) itself returns 0 despite textMSG containing characters above 128. The line itself is inside a remote cffunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/regexp_08.html), ColdFusion's regex implementation doesn't support the \u escape sequence (and, indeed, I am fairly certain it's completely unaware of the concept of unicode).

To do what you want here, you're gonna have to use [Java regexes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Ah my apologies, missed noticing that small tidbit. So ColdFusion doesn't support unicode regex, despite ColdFusion being built on Java, and now I have to use Java, through ColdFusion, which is built on Java. Nice.

Comment: Well.... yes. It used ORO because - I suppose - it was closest to what it used to support from before CF was Java-based. I wouldn't lament too much about using Java regexes in CF as it's dead easy (and hardly any more code than doing it in native CF). If it's a help, I discuss how to do so on my blog: http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part.html